# Allow another developer to manage a Chrome extension/app in the Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've done plenty of searching and I can't find ANY information about having multiple developers working on a Chrome extension.

Basically, I just want to grant another developer access to manage my Chrome extension in the Chrome Developers Dashboard. (ie so that it is listed in their Chrome developer Dashboard and they can publish it/change the logo etc).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**EDIT [6 Aug 2013](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/08/group-based-publishing-in-chrome-web.html)** - The Group Publishing feature allows organisations to create a group such that the extensions can be managed by multiple developers. For more info, see [Group Publishing](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing).

---

<sub>*Old answer*</sub>

An extension in the Chrome Web Store can be managed by only one Google account.

- If you want to have multiple developers manage the extension, create a Google account for your company, pay 5$ to get the right to publish and share the credentials within the company.
- If you want to transfer ownership of an extension to another account, fill in [this form](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer).

Assets (screenshots) are usually not updated very often. On the other hand, it's common to update the extension's source code and description, so letting the main developer manage the extension listing makes sense.

Comment: It seems you can publish extensions to your domain / company without paying the developer fee. But the publishing group option is not available, is it necessary to pay the fee in order to create a publishing group even if the publishing group can only publish to the domain?

Comment: This does not work anymore. There is no such option for group publishing in the newly updated Chrome dashboard (as of 24 Sep 2018).

Comment: You can use the old dashboard though.

Comment: @jonathanwiesel I know it is over a year ago that you asked your question. I did not see the option to enable group publishing before I paid the developers fee. I do see the option after I paid the developers fee. So it seems like you need to pay the developers fee before you can use this option.